# python memoryError when plotting heatmaps from a big dataset

Tags: python, memory, matplotlib, out-of-memory, data-visualization

For my thesis I'm plotting the electric field around multiple nanostructures. This was the easy part. Now I'm trying to get four different fields next to each other using (2x2) subplots and it's killing me.

The fields are sampled at 2500 intervals in the x and y-direction for a total of 6.250.000 points and saved as (x, y, Efield). The resulting datasets are around 240 Mb each. When I load a single file and plot it everything goes ok but when I plot four side by side it is too much and I get a memoryError.

The code works fine for a smaller sample (500x500) but the accuracy was too low.  A stripped down version of the code I use and the Error message are below.

Another point that may be important is that the simulations are run on a cluster with the following specifications:

Type:    E5-2650 v2
Clock:   2.60 GHz
Scratch: 870 GB
MemorY:  64 GB QPI 8.00 GT/s
Cache:   20 MB
Cores:   16
Python:  2.7.9

```
def plotMulitpleHeamapSubplot(files, title, subtitles):

    # Create the figure
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2, sharex='col', sharey='row')
    fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
    grid = [axes[0][0], axes[1][0], axes[0][1], axes[1][1]]

    for i in range(1,5):
        filePath = files[i-1]
        ax = grid[i-1]

        # Make the heatmap in the subplot
        im = plotHeatMap(filePath, 0.001, rectangles=(0.233, 0.150, .5), ylab = "z direction", title=subtitles[i-1], fig=fig, ax=ax, zRange=(0,1.5))


    # Make it look good
    axes[0][0].set_xlabel("")
    axes[0][1].set_xlabel("")
    axes[0][1].set_ylabel("")
    axes[1][1].set_ylabel("")

    # More looking good
    fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=36, y=1.01)
    cax = fig.add_axes([.925, 0.1, 0.035, 0.8])
    cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
    cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=26) 

    # Here it crashes
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=.1)
    fig.savefig(path+str(title) + ".png", bbox_inches='tight')


def plotHeatmap()
    x, y, value = [], [], []

    # Load everything from a file.
    # File is formated with a point (x,y,z) on each line
    for line in f:
        a, b, c = line.split(",")
        x.append(float(a))
        y.append(float(b))
        value.append(float(c))

    # Not really important, use this to fill the grid later
    scaledX = np.array([round(xi) for xi in (np.array(x) / resolution)])
    scaledY = np.array([round(yi) for yi in (np.array(y) / resolution)])
    scaledX = scaledX - min(scaledX) 
    scaledY = scaledY - min(scaledY)

    # Create the grid and fill it with the z values
    size = int(len(x)**.5)
    grid = np.zeros((size, size))

    # The scaled arrays contain integers so I can use them for the index.
    for i in range(len(x)):
        grid[scaledX[i], scaledY[i]] = value[i]


    # Use the original x and y lists to get the correct grids.
    x, y = np.mgrid[slice(min(x), max(x) + resolution, resolution),
                slice(min(y), max(y)+ resolution, resolution)]


    cax = ax.pcolormesh(x, y, grid, vmin=zRange[0], vmax=zRange[1])


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonScripts.py", line 1452, in <module>
    plotMulitpleHeamapSubplotControler(0)
  File "pythonScripts.py", line 1211, in plotMulitpleHeamapSubplotControler
    plotMulitpleHeamapSubplot(fileList, title, titleList)
  File "pythonScripts.py", line 1242, in plotMulitpleHeamapSubplot
    fig.savefig(PATH+str(title) + ".png", bbox_inches='tight')
  File "/sara/sw/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1470, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/sara/sw/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2151, in print_figure
    bbox = a.get_window_extent(renderer)
  File "/sara/sw/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 207, in get_window_extent
    return self.get_datalim(transforms.IdentityTransform())
  File "/sara/sw/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 180, in get_datalim
    paths = self.get_paths()
  File "/sara/sw/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 1675, in get_paths
    self.set_paths()
  File "/sara/sw/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 1680, in set_paths
    self._meshWidth, self._meshHeight, self._coordinates)
  File "/sara/sw/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 1706, in convert_mesh_to_paths
    return [Path(x) for x in points]
  File "/sara/sw/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/path.py", line 157, in __init__
    self._update_values()
  File "/sara/sw/python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/path.py", line 205, in _update_values
    self._has_nonfinite = not np.isfinite(self._vertices).all()
MemoryError
```

Comment: I would take a look in Bcolz (http://bcolz.blosc.org). It helpd me plot 2.4M points with 41 dimensions each on a map using matplotlib. It lets you use large NumPy arrays without loading them at once to RAM. Another option I would suggest is to plot each subplot separately and then stitch them together.

Comment: Since it works for a single `subplot`; have you checked how much memory your script uses in that case? And if you are working on a cluster, there might be a memory limit for a single process (or user).

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I'll look into bcolz. 
@Bart I do not know how much memory my scipt uses when I plot a single heatmap and the values I posted are for the Node I'm doing my simulations on so I can use "all" of it.

Comment: If your user has right, try to write `ulimit -s unlimited` to increase stack size, its may help.

Comment: I'm guessing that is the plot that is consuming most of the memory. Are you in Python 32 or 64bit? Also notice that you probably won't need such a big resolution **for** plotting (an high definition resolution is 1920 × 1080, you would need 4K to get more pixels than your plot which is 2500 x 2500). Could you try plotting `im[0:-1:2, 0:-1:2]` or even `im[0:-1:3, 0:-1:3]` (one in every two values, and one in every three respectively) and see if you find any major difference?

Comment: @armatita that worked, thanks!